# Getting this error "Unexpected empty object pattern" while using react , useStateValue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am following the WhatsApp clone on YouTube, I did exactly what they were doing but I don't know why I'm getting this error. I was

I read a lot of blogs, but I couldn't resolve it.

In app, it gives this error and couldn't dismiss.
./src/App.js Line 10: 'dispatch' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

In login, it gives this error.
./src/Login.js Line 9:  Unexpected empty object pattern  no-empty-pattern

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./Login.css";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { auth, provider } from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { actionTypes } from "./reducer";

function Login() {
  const [value, dispatch] = useStateValue({});
  // const [value, dispatch] = useStateValue({})
  // const [{ type, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  const signIn = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        dispatch({
          type: actionTypes.SET_USER,
          user: result.user,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="login__container">
        <img
          src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/whatsapp-logo-png-hd-2.png"
          alt=""
        />
        <div className="login__text">
          <h1>Sign in to WhatsApp</h1>
        </div>
        <Button onClick={signIn}>Sign In with Google</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Chat from "./Chat";
import Login from "./Login";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";

function App() {
  const [{ user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {!user ? (
        <Login />
      ) : (
        <div className="app__body">
          <Router>
            <Sidebar />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/rooms/:roomId" element={<Chat />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Chat />} />
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

```js
export const initialState = {
  user: null,
};

export const actionTypes = {
  SET_USER: "SET_USER",
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.SET_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Please provide some code so other can see and give suggestions.

Comment: @Senen This is an EsLint rule for indicating that are unused variables in the code. You can either remove the unused variable or make the rule as a warning rather than an error. In this case the dispatch  is not being used after the declaration in app.js

Please refer: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/eslint/rules#:~:text=The%20%22no%2Dunused%2Dvars,only%20rule%20violations%20are%20warnings.

Comment: what about empty object pattern?

Comment: The empty object pattern is also an EsLint rule indicating that one of your  object variables are empty. In this case const [value, dispatch] = useStateValue({}); . Here the initial state value is an empty object.

Comment: I removed them and added the above line you wrote, but in vain. I read that document but couldn't understand how to make the rule a warning rather than an error.

Comment: @PriyenMehta, hey can you spot an error now?